# Soundmanager2 takes several seconds to load MP3 stream, only when using HTML5

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2, internet-radio

So I'm trying to play an MP3 radio stream (generated by Icecast2) using Soundmanager2. When Soundmanager2 uses Flash, the stream instantly starts playing when I open the page with the autoplay Soundmanager2 element in it. However, if I disable Flash (or use a platform that doesn't support Flash) and use HTML5, the sound only starts playing after 6-10 seconds. This is very annoying, since potential listeners have short attention and may end up closing the window within those 10 seconds.

Is there any way to make Soundmanager2 start playing the stream instantly when using HTML5?

Comment: last year browsers couldn't even do streams using the <audio> tag, so give it a few months and things will likely improve.

Comment: Did you set the partials / range requests correctly?

Comment: If you are talking about the range HTTP header, it's "Range:bytes=0-". Given that IceCast is made specifically for streaming radio I assume it's handling the HTTP headers correctly. In any case, there's no way to change the headers of IceCast's streams.

Comment: What browsers have you tested on? Do they all that that long?